# Every image take 1 line

Tags: html, css, image, tumblr

I know it is not a very serious issue but I do not know how to solve it.  Every picture takes **1** **line** in post so it takes a lot of space. How can I fix it?

- [**GitHub Code**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xSOADx/The-Default-Network/master/Theme%20code)

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: `display: inline-block`

Comment: @J. Titus Where should I paste it to?

Comment: You are required to place a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem here, not some third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve PICTURES OF CODE DON'T COUNT!

Comment: Your `img` CSS definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.media {
    display: inline;
}
```

**This is how it looks :**
[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: Thats weird, I did that and it worked, the screenshot is attached

Comment: I set "display:block" so it didn't work and then I replace
it back. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SergeyRakhmalevich my pleasure :)

Answer (score -1):

You can play with `display` CSS property on the `img` tag.
This property will change the way that images are display.

I recommend you to play with it in your browser, for example Chrome, which have a good console and autocomplete to show you all display values available.

Comment: don't play, CODE!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you wish to make a comment, delete this one and put it in the comments section under the answer.